# Create DF with number of times two people took breaks together for all pairs

Tags: sql, r

I have a dataframe of when people took breaks. It has their employee id, clock in time, clock out time.

```
library(tidyverse)
breaks %>%
 head()

  EmployeeID         PunchInTime        PunchOutTime
1     105210 2018-10-19 07:57:07 2018-10-19 08:31:52
2     106556 2018-10-19 06:31:03 2018-10-19 07:04:27
3     100412 2018-10-19 06:29:42 2018-10-19 06:46:18
4     101917 2018-10-19 06:25:05 2018-10-19 08:01:03
5     102508 2018-10-19 06:04:02 2018-10-19 06:22:54
6     100859 2018-10-19 06:00:20 2018-10-19 06:35:33
```

I am still exploring the data, but I am interested in some variety of when the breaks overlapped. The end goal is to examine groups of people who take breaks together. To get there, I want to create something like an adjacency matrix (in the network analysis context). *Right now, I am just trying to get a count for if they overlap at all, but I also think being able to see if a pair overlapped for something like over ten minutes would be useful too.*

This is one of those tricky problems (for me) where I don't even know how to start. I have tried one R strategy to limited gains. I attempted to spread the employee ids into columns, list the break intervals (using lubridate's `interval` function. I didn't really have a next steps in mind, and it doesn't really work either. Though, it does technically run. Here is that code.

```
library(lubridate)
> breaks %>% 
+   mutate(
+     BreakInterval = interval(PunchInTime, PunchOutTime)
+   ) %>%
+   select(
+     EmployeeID,
+     BreakInterval
+     ) %>% 
+   group_by(EmployeeID) %>%
+   mutate(BreakNoPerEmployee = row_number()) %>%
+   spread(EmployeeID, BreakInterval) -> mutations
> View(mutations)
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “Interval” object: Inconsistent lengths: spans = 378, start 
dates = 79002
```

A second R strategy I was thinking about was to do some sort of for loop, but I can't think through the logic to create the paired overlap counts.  This seems like maybe it might be easier done in SQL (as the data is originally stored there anyway) with a subquery / self join. I have both SQL and R experience and could do it in either, but I am more experienced with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely not the most elegant solution, but here's an attempt. There is a cross join performed, so if you have a lot of data this could blow up quickly:

#### solution

```
library(tidyverse)

breaks %<>% group_by(EmployeeID) %>% mutate(break_no = row_number())

b1 <- breaks %>% 
  setNames(paste0(names(.), "1"))

b2 <- breaks %>% 
  setNames(paste0(names(.), "2"))

# create a paired comparison for each break
breaks_merge <- merge(b1, b2, by = NULL) %>% 
  # filter depending on your end goal, might be a good sanity check
  filter(EmployeeID1 != EmployeeID2) %>% 
  mutate(int_b1 = interval(PunchInTime1, PunchOutTime1),
         int_b2 = interval(PunchInTime2, PunchOutTime2),
         breaks_overlap = int_overlaps(int_b1, int_b2))

# adjacency matrix a little awkward because of multiple employees with multiple breaks
breaks_adj <- breaks_merge %>%
  select(-matches("^[Punch|int]")) %>%
  unite("Emp1_break", EmployeeID1, break_no1, sep = "_") %>%
  unite("Emp2_break", EmployeeID2, break_no2, sep = "_") %>%
  spread(Emp2_break, breaks_overlap)

> breaks_adj
  Emp1_break 100412_1 100859_1 101917_1 102508_1 105210_1 106556_1
1   100412_1       NA     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
2   100859_1     TRUE       NA     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE
3   101917_1     TRUE     TRUE       NA    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
4   102508_1    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE       NA    FALSE    FALSE
5   105210_1    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE    FALSE       NA    FALSE
6   106556_1     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE       NA
```

#### data

```
breaks <- structure(list(EmployeeID = c(105210L, 106556L, 100412L, 101917L, 
102508L, 100859L), PunchInTime = structure(c(1539961027, 1539955863, 
1539955782, 1539955505, 1539954242, 1539954020), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), PunchOutTime = structure(c(1539963112, 
1539957867, 1539956778, 1539961263, 1539955374, 1539956133), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("EmployeeID", "PunchInTime", 
"PunchOutTime"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Note

Also, if you're playing around with `dplyr` and `lubridate` intervals, there are some [unexpected errors you may encounter](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2568).